# Retrofit observable works only once

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-android

I understand that, by default, observables created by retrofit are "cold" observables.

I have this specific call to my server endpoint

```
@POST("oauth/token")
Observable<Token> signIn(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
```

When I do:

```
public class LoginUseCase extends Subscriber<Profile> {
    public void logIn(String username, String password) {
        Subscription subscription = myApi.signIn(username, password)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this);
        this.add(subscription);
    }
}
```

I receive the `onNext` `onError` `onComplete` callbacks, as you would expect.

The problem arises when the login fails and I try again. Calling the `login()` method a second time doesn't trigger the http call, and I don't get any callbacks.

By the way, Im doing this on my `onComplete()` method

```
@Override
public void onCompleted() {
    this.unsubscribe();
}
```

Is there a way to tell retrofit/rxandroid to re make the http call everytime I call `myApi.signin()`. Am I even approaching this the right way?

Notes:
- Im using dagger2 in my project and the myApi object is a singleton. 
- I'm able to reproduce the error even when I use different username/pass configs between the first and second try

Comment: Without the code, i'm guessing there is only one subscriber in your fragment/activity. You need to re-emit the observable for it to work. Is there only one instance of LoginUseCase subscriber in your context?

Comment: Yes, theres only one instance of LoginUseCase in my fragment. How do I re-emit the observable? Thanks!

Comment: Jus reinitialize it, or if you can edit your question to contain the part where you use the object, I can show you the required changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once `Subscriber#unsubscribe()` is called that subscriber can never receive new values. You will need to recreate your subscriber each time you want to subscribe to a new observable.

What is happening is that in the call to `Subscriber#add(Subscription)` it sees that the subscriber has already been unsubscribed and immediately cancels the new subscription.

Comment: Yup, that did it! I didn't know subscribers were disposable. I'll read up a bit on why this is, I'll have to re structure my code to create a new subscriber every time. Thanks for the help